# Is there any control for tree view in .net MAUI?

Tags: .net, maui, .net-maui

I want to implement tree view in .net so is there any control implemented for tree view in .net MAUI ?

Comment: There is no such a control in the .Net Maui, the `TreeView` is still in the maui's plan.

Comment: Look [here](https://enisn-projects.io/docs/en/uranium/latest/themes/material/components/TreeView)

Comment: No. Take a look at this blog post: https://dev.to/icebeam7/creating-a-treeview-control-in-net-maui-49mp